# How to split an HTML code into two columns with image on the right?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, divide

I'm using wordpress to build a website and currently have the about page done but I want to add images to the right hand side of  the page. I cannot put in any css into the template because it already has its own css. It accepts html tags though. So how would I go about getting the three images I want on the right hand side of the page? Here is the code that I do have:

```
<div id="header">
  <h4 style="color: #6f9458;">Welcome to the Greens at Amyclae!</h4>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <div class="col">
    <p>my text here </p>
    <h6 style="color: #6f9458;">Overview</h6>
    <p>more text here</p>
   <h6> Stafford County Public Schools serve the Greens at Amyclae 
subdivision.</h6>
    <ul>
        <li>Winding Creek Elementary School</li>
        <li>Rodney Thompson Middle School</li>
        <li>Colonial Forge High School</li>
    </ul>
    <h6 style="color:#6f9458">Management Agency:
    Corporation
    Fredericksburg, VA 22401 </h6>
  </div>

  <div class="col" style="float:right">
    <img src="sample.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is what I'm looking for:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what 'It accepts html tags though', means. You could put CSS inline or modify the template. Do you have a mockup image of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: You can't just add css to the css already in the "template"?

Comment: @JakeParis if I type in any css, it just shows up as plain text.

Comment: Is the it last `div class="col"` where you want to place the 3 images?

Comment: @JakeParis yes the last div container is where I want the three images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this. The image is floating right but the paragraph tag will wrap around the image.

```html
<div style="overflow:hidden;background-color:blue;width:100%">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50" alt="" style="float:right">
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero.
  </p>
</div>

<div style="overflow:hidden;background-color:#000088;width:100%">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x75" alt="" style="float:right">
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero.
  </p>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DanielGale/jkebwL0b/

Comment: Do I treat this as a separate container or do I have integrate my current text into this?

Comment: as long as the parent element does something like overflow:hidden or clear:both and the child element uses float:right, you should be okay. If you want to use multiple images per div, then you may need to use padding to space them horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

You can use inline style.

```
<div class="col" style="float:right">
    <img src="sample.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: By putting that in the last div container?

Comment: No, that _is_ the last div container. Add the `style="float:right;" ` attribute to that existing <div>

Comment: I just an example. You can write inline style like this.

Comment: @JakeParis I meant by adding style= into the last div container I already have.

Comment: That will float the whole <div>. Are you trying to float them individually or as a group?

Comment: @DanielGale as a group

Comment: float:right will also make the image jump out of the Div without a clear fix or overflow set.

Comment: @DanielGale Yes I'm just noticing that. It puts the pics at the bottom right hand side of the page stacked on top of another. How do I get it to equally split the page, have the photos on the right with slight spacing between them stacked horizontally?

Comment: can you upload an image of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @DanielGale added the photo to the question!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to modify the themes' css (it's actually better not to do it) or to create a child theme (it's not always really necessary), and you're familiar with css, adding classes and ids, you can use a plugin like this one: https://pl.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-js/ and put your css there. If it makes any problems it's easy to reverse (by simply deleting the modified code within this plugins' menu) with no harm to the theme.